# Prove that if $0\leq a < b$ and $0 \leq c <d$, then $ac<bd$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Proof:

Suppose $0\leq a<b$ and $0\leq c < d$. Let $P$ denote the set of positive real numbers, we see that  $$a, b-a, c, d-c \in P.$$

By closure under multiplication, 
$$(b-a)(d-c) = bd-bc-ad+ac \in P,$$ 
$$a(d-c)=ad-ac \in P.$$ 
So by closure under addition, $(bd-bc-ad+ac)+(ad-ac)=bd-bc\in P$. That is, $bc<bd$.

Since $c(b-a)=bc-ac \implies ac<bc$, we have shown that $ac<bc<bd$. Thus, $ac<bd$. $\square$

Must I show something else with regards to the transitivity of inequalities or does this proof work as is?

Thanks.

Comment: $$  bd-ac = bd - bc + bc - ac = b(d-c) + (b-a)c$$

Comment: $ac < ad$ from the definition of $c<d$ and because $\frac{b}{a} > 1$ we mulitply just the right side by $\frac{b}{a}$ to get $ac < ad < bd$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *cannot* conclude that $a,c\in P$ (unless your definition of $P$ has $0\in P$). However, we *can* conclude that $b,d\in P.$

Fortunately, we can proceed more directly. Since $b,d-c\in P,$ then $bd-bc=b(d-c)\in P$ by closure under multiplication, and so $bc<bd.$ Now, **if** $c\in P,$ then we can similarly conclude that $ac<bc.$ Otherwise, we have $c=0,$ whence $ac=0=bc.$ Regardless, we have $ac\le bc,$ so since $bc<bd,$ then we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Prove first that if  $0\leq x<1$ and $0\leq y<1$ then $0\leq xy<1$. This is clear because, for positive multiplying N by a smaller number than 1 decrements the absolute value of N then 
$0\leq xy<1$.

Now apply this to $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$